# What was/is 'User Accounts' for

Tags: windows

In more modern Windows OS's there is a window called 'User Accounts' and from what I can see it can only be activated using a command (control userpasswords2), so it is not invoked in the UI in any way.

Was this always true or is it in the GUI and I just have not seen it?
or is it part of the GUI of some older windows OS.

I know that this command also works but looks like more of a system/shell command than a user intended command:

```
rundll32 netplwiz.dll,UsersRunDll
```

Box in question:

[image]

Comment: You can still access User Accounts GUI, outside of using the command line, to display it.  It might have a different look (or multiple looks even depending on the version of Windows) but the same functionality can be accessed. *I am honestly not sure what you are asking though*

Comment: Im asking if and where this box can be found in the actual user interface instead of typing a command.

Answer (score 0):

> With Windows 7, everyone who uses your computer can have their own user account.
>
> If you wanted to, you could have a single account on your computer that everyone could use. But having multiple accounts has some advantages. If each user has his or her own account, then each person will have his or her own desktop for organizing files and folders.

http://www.gcflearnfree.org/windows7/managing-user-accounts-and-parental-controls/1/

Go to Control Panel and then User Accounts.  Its the same thing as your picture.

Comment: Its primarily depending on your configuration like conputers Domain membership. If you activate classic logon screen (Not sure if its called exactly like this) it should be the Standard Form showed by control panels ´User Accounts´

Comment: from what Ive found, even with classic logon, or joined to a domain, windows either displays the control panel splash screen for 'user accounts' or the 'user accounts' found in microsoft managment console (lusrmgr.msc) not the box I showed above.